# Filter nested JSON but maintain the object structure

Tags: json, jq

Consider the below JSON:

```
[
 {
 "vd":[    
        {
            "key":1
        },
        {
            "key":2    
        }
      ]   
  }
]
```

Now I would like to filter based on the filter `key==1`. So the result should be:

```
[
 {
    "vd": [
        {
            "key": 1
        }
    ]
  }
 ]
```

Is there a way to achieve this using `jq`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traverse to the array in question `.[].vd`, and update `|=` with a `map` based on a `select` using your criteria `.key == 1`:

```bash
jq '.[].vd |= map(select(.key == 1))'
```

```json
[
  {
    "vd": [
      {
        "key": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/zum2tuif9pp)

Comment: Thanks ! but 
jq '.[].vd[] |= select(.key == 5)' also responds with a json , should it not be empty [] ?

Comment: Race condition. Use `map` instead on the whole array. Updated the answer.